# Android Camera takePicture() failed

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, surfaceview

I've been trying to take a picture using the Camera using a Surface Preview in Android. The Surface Preview spans the entire screen in the layout.

Whenever I call takePicture, it fails and says I have no enabled preview.

Here's the activity variables, picture methods, and the camera picture taking code (it's in onResume() ):

```
public class FawkesRCActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

  SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
  SurfaceHolder mHolder;
  public Camera mCamera;

  ...


  Camera.PictureCallback camHolla = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
      String photoFile = "F_Auton.jpg";
      File sdDir = Environment
              .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

      String filename =sdDir + File.separator + photoFile;

      File pictureFile = new File(filename);

      try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Errored:", e.getMessage());
      }

    }
  };

  public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
    if (mCamera == camera) { return; }

    stopPreviewAndFreeCamera();

    mCamera = camera;

    if (mCamera != null) {
      List<Camera.Size> localSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
      try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      // Important: Call startPreview() to start updating the preview
      // surface. Preview must be started before you can take a picture.
      mCamera.startPreview();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

  }

  public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    mCamera.startPreview();
  }

  public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
    if (mCamera != null) {
      // Call stopPreview() to stop updating the preview surface.
      mCamera.stopPreview();
    }
  }

  /**
   * When this function returns, mCamera will be null.
   */
  private void stopPreviewAndFreeCamera() {

    if (mCamera != null) {
      // Call stopPreview() to stop updating the preview surface.
      mCamera.stopPreview();

      // Important: Call release() to release the camera for use by other
      // applications. Applications should release the camera immediately
      // during onPause() and re-open() it during onResume()).
      mCamera.release();

      mCamera = null;
    }
  }


  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    FawkesRCActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(FawkesRCActivity.this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        // Search for the front facing camera
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        int camId=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
          Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
          Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
          if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
            camId=i;
          }
        }
        if (safeCameraOpen(camId))Log.e("Camera","All Good"); else Log.e("Camera","Errored");
        try{
          SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(0);
          mCamera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
      //    mCamera.startPreview();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
          mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, camHolla);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }
    });

    super.onResume();
  }

 private boolean safeCameraOpen(int id) {
    boolean qOpened = false;

    try {
      releaseCameraAndPreview();
      mCamera = Camera.open(id);
      qOpened = (mCamera != null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "failed to open Camera");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return qOpened;
  }

  private void releaseCameraAndPreview() {
    setCamera(null);
    if (mCamera != null) {
      mCamera.release();
      mCamera = null;
    }
  }

}
```

And here's the error:

```
12-31 20:00:15.407    3244-5501/? E/Camera2Client﹕ takePicture: Camera 0: Cannot take picture without preview enabled
12-31 20:00:15.408    6988-6988/? W/System.err﹕ java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
12-31 20:00:15.408    6988-6988/? W/System.err﹕ at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
12-31 20:00:15.408    6988-6988/? W/System.err﹕ at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1434)
12-31 20:00:15.408    6988-6988/? W/System.err﹕ at org.fawkes.fawkesrc.FawkesRCActivity$5.run(FawkesRCActivity.java:327)
12-31 20:00:15.408    6988-6988/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:5524)
12-31 20:00:15.408    6988-6988/? W/System.err﹕ at org.fawkes.fawkesrc.FawkesRCActivity.onResume(FawkesRCActivity.java:298)
12-31 20:00:15.408    6988-6988/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1258)
12-31 20:00:15.408    6988-6988/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6327)
12-31 20:00:15.408    6988-6988/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
12-31 20:00:15.408    6988-6988/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
12-31 20:00:15.408    6988-6988/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
12-31 20:00:15.408    6988-6988/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
12-31 20:00:15.408    6988-6988/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
12-31 20:00:15.409    6988-6988/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-31 20:00:15.409    6988-6988/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-31 20:00:15.409    6988-6988/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
12-31 20:00:15.409    6988-6988/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-31 20:00:15.409    6988-6988/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
12-31 20:00:15.409    6988-6988/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

After scouring forums for a few hours I'm completely lost, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camera operations are not immediate, and often not synchronous. Some devices require significant delay between startPreview() and takePicture(), e.g. on OnePlus One you need at least 100ms.

Minimal fix to your code could be

```
    try{
      SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(0);
      mCamera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
  //    mCamera.startPreview();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

mSurfaceView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, camHolla);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }, 100);

        super.onResume();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but I think you didn't call `mCamera.startPreview()` before you take the picture. You may try to call it before that.

You may take a look on this  [CameraFragment Sample](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/821736e1fb70be2c827c9e6a35a7739762523897/samples/Honeycomb-Gallery/src/com/example/android/hcgallery/CameraFragment.java) as a reference to start the camera preview and so on.